# #1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses001'@'localhost' to database 'test_db'

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, database, phpmyadmin

I have purchase i hosting with cpanel in godaddy and I am migrating a WordPress site, but the problem when I am trying to import database it gave me this error `#1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses001'@'localhost' to database 'test_db'`

I am accessing `phpMyAdmin` from cPanel but before that I have created the database `test_db` created user associated with it so when I navigate to `phpMyAdmin` it show me that i am logged in with the user `cpses001'@'localhost` which the same user used for cPanel login and it doesn't show the user that I have created. "the user I have created have full privileges".

There is no way to logout and login to `phpMyAdmin` from the interface, so I tried to download the last version of `phpMyAdmin` and uploaded to site root directory  then o navigate to it and logged in with the user that have full privileges and when I started to import the database it throw the same error.

I have contacted `Godaddy` support but they told me this out of their scope. so now I am stuck and i have no idea what to do as I tried all the ways.
Hope someone here can save hours of pain.
thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to import the database?  Through phpMyAdmin?  From some other web app?  From a command line?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller through the import button in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @anie are you trying to import a .sql file?